# Error getting Query Data from MySQL with PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Having an issue getting the MySQL Data in my Database.
I don't know if the code is fine or I have missed something,
please give me an idea of how to get the data from my database.

[image: This is the Data I want to Edit]

[image: This is the Edit Form when editing the Data]

This is my Query in Time Data

```php
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * from timetable";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if($result){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $t_id=$row["t_id"];
            $time=$row["t_time"];
            $t_time=date("h:i A", strtotime($row["t_time"])); ?>
            <option <?php echo $update && $up_time == $time ? 'selected' : ''; ?> value='<?= $time ?>'><?= $t_time ?><br></option>
    <?php   }
    }
?>
```

This is my Query in my Employee Data

```php
<?php
    $query = "SELECT * from employee";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $query);
    if($result){
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $e_id=$row["id"];
            $name=$row["e_name"]; ?>
            <option <?php echo $update && $up_employee == $e_id ? 'selected' : ''; ?> value="<?= $e_name ?>"><?= $name ?><br></option>
            <?php 
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Is `$db` ok? Did you connect and selected the database: `$db = mysqli_connect(...);`  
(Btw I am not sure if the `<br>` is ok inside the `<option>`)

Comment: yes the $db is okay

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Did you connect and selected the database: `$db = mysqli_connect(...);`

(I am not sure if the `<br>` is ok inside the `<option>`.)

Comment: i got Error 500

Comment: This `<?= $e_name ?>` is the short form of `<?php echo $e_name; ?>`